# Back to previous activity after some Alert Dialogs within a loop

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In a second activity I would like to have some Alert Dialogs within a loop as in:

```
  public void testAlert(View v)
        {
        AlertDialog alertDialog; 
        for (int k = 0; k< 4; k++){
           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
           // set title
           alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Title n. "+k);
           // set dialog message
           alertDialogBuilder
              .setMessage("Click OK to replace!")
              .setCancelable(false)
              .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                 }
                })
              .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                 }
              });
              // create alert dialog
              alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
              // show it
              alertDialog.show();

         } 
         finish();
  }
```

and then come back to the previous activity, but when I add finish() I get:

```
E/WindowManager( 9416): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.secondscreen.Screen2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{422ae1f0 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-480,275} that was originally added here
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at com.example.secondscreen.Screen2.testAlert(Screen2.java:47)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3855)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/WindowManager( 9416):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[...]
```

How should I handle this?

Comment: This isn't doing what you want it to, and is actually prone to a number of issues. It is instantiating and showing four different AlertDialogs in a single instance. Before you even have a chance to respond to the AlertDialogs they are either reinstantiated or the activity closes. If you are showing an AlertDialog, before you reinstantiate that AlertDialog or finish the Activity containing the dialog, you need to make sure you dismiss the dialog to keep it from leaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you open a dialog and then quit the activity. Like the dialog leak...

If you want to wait that the user clicked in your dialog you must set your finish just after `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: By checking the values of k I realized that the AlertDialogs are not visualized with the same order of for,
but with the opposite order: k = 3, 2, 1, 0, so with the condition if(check==0) (after dialog.dismiss())  it works:                                                           `dialog.dismiss();
 if(check==0)finish();`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.finish();
```

Or

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,Previous.class));
```

If that suits your requirement.